# storing multiple values of a variable in cookie and comparing

Tags: php, cookies

How can i store multiple values for a variable in cookie using php, for example
$id = 1,2,4,5
Then how can i compare the stored values with a variable? for example, $new_id=4, i want to check if $new_id value exists in the stored values of $id in cookie.
Thanks for help and have a nice day.

Comment: This can be done, but why do you want to do this in a cookie? Are you sure that is the optimal approach?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just want to do so that if a user selects some options, they can be stored temporarily. I thought about cookies as i thought storing in database might be just useless? Could you please suggest some optimal approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store arbitrary strings in cookie elements, so a serialized array should work. Example:

```
// To store:
$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
setcookie('ids', serialize($ids));

// To retrieve:
$serialized = $_COOKIE['ids'];
$ids = unserialize($serialized);
// sanity check: $ids needs to be an array.
assert(is_array($ids));

// Now let's check:
if (in_array(4, $ids)) {
    // Yes, it's here.
}
```

A few caveats though:

- The cookie is completely in the hands of the client, and cookie values should never be trusted. Treat them just like you would treat query string parameters or POST data.
- Cookies offer very limited storage (IIRC, the standard gives you 4096 bytes to work with).

With these in mind, it might be a better idea to store the array in `$_SESSION` instead - this will give you virtually unlimited storage, and the only way for the client application to fiddle with the values is through your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very useful information. Could you please give an example to store with session? and also, is serialize efficient way to store lots of data? (for example 1000 ids)

Comment: Just call session_start() at the beginning of your script, and after that, you can read/write to/from the $_SESSION[] superglobal. Read up on the documentation, it's really simple. Serializing is pretty efficient, but why do you need to store 1000 IDs per user? It might be useful if you could give us a bit more background to see what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to make so that if a user selects some products, and adds to the cart, i want to store those product id's in the browser, so that even if the user leaves the page and products are in the cart, they can still be in cart.. Of course 1000 was just an example.

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case, I'd suggest you store the shopping cart items in a database table. Much cleaner and easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

to use the multiple value you can use the **array** and then to store it you can **serialize** ( and **unserialize**) the array.

**To create array:**  $array = array(1,2,3,4);

**To compare:** if (in_array(2,$array)) echo "Yep";

**To serialize the data to be stored:** $store = serialize($array);

Ten you will be able to create the cookie with $store data and then use unserialize($store) to reconvert data in array.

[Serialize Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following snippet.

```
// do Stuff to retrieve value of $id from cookie.

// explode variable to array
$idArr = explode(',' , $id);

// check existence of new_id in cookie variable.
if(in_array($new_id , $idArr)){

// new_id exist in cookie variable

}
```

Hope this will help

Thanks!

Hussain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one out of many solutions (syntax may contain errors):

```
// Create an array with the values you want to store in the cookie
$id = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

// Create cookie
set_cookie('id', implode(',', $id));

// Get cookie
$id = explode(',', $_COOKIE['id']);

// Test value
if(in_array($newId, $id) === true) {
  // Value is in the array
}
```

Restrictions:
The values stored in $id cannot include commas, choose another separator if you need to store commas

Answer (score 0):

Store array in cookie and then compare them